# How do I delete a file from depot, but leave local copy in tact?

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to learn Perforce and want to delete a file from the depot(easy to do with p4 delete, p4 submit), but that deletes it from the client machine dir structure as well.  I want to keep my local file in my directory intact.

The only way I can see to do this would be to move it out of the hierarchy that is under Perforce control before deleting.  I was able to get my file back by syncing an earlier version.

Maybe I set up my client workspace wrong?  Or am I misunderstanding a fundamental concept of source control? The client workspace is /home/user and I did it this way so I could add any file under my home directory without getting an error about the file not being under client's root.

FYI - Linux client and server running P4D/LINUX26X86/2009.1/222893 (2009/11/12)

Any advice appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is any way to keep a file you are deleting under Perforce.  There is good reason for this, as if the file is deleted in the depot there is no reason (from a source code control perspective) to keep a copy in the client workspace.

I suspect the issue is the way you are using Perforce.

From what you have written it seems that you are using Perforce to backup/track files in your home directory structure.  So the way you are using Perforce the "master" is in your home directory and the "copies" are in the depot.

This is not the intended use of a source control system as I understand it.

The master copy of all files are actually what is in the depot.  From the depot, multiple clients (views) are made for purposes such as making changes, testing, and so on.  The clients are transitory and can be created and deleted as required.

To do what you want to do you may need to rethink how you are using Perforce.

Comment: I found a good reason, someone checked in a bunch of user properties files, so now I can't configure my personal environment unless I first check out the user files.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to do this, by going behind Perforce's back. Do the following:

1. Rename the file you want to delete to something new
2. Run `p4 delete` on the original filename
3. `p4 submit` the change
4. Rename the file back to the original name

Answer (score 1):

some of the other commands take a parameter that lets you fake the action, but delete doesn't. You could always make a new client, do the delete in that workspace.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the Workspace tab go to folder containing file(s) to remove from source
2. Right-click on that directory (or from *File* menu) and choose **Open command window here**

   - Note - If you open your own command prompt in the source directory you may encounter this error:
     `"Client 'your-client' unknown - use 'client' command to create it."`
3. Enter command `p4 delete -k <file_to_delete>`
4. Change will be added to your P4V Helix changelist ready to check in

Answer (score 0):

The command `p4 obliterate` is what you are looking for I think.

[https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.091/manuals/cmdref/obliterate.html#:~:text=Once%20p4%20obliterate%20completes%2C%20it,as%20being%20under%20Perforce%20control](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.091/manuals/cmdref/obliterate.html#:%7E:text=Once%20p4%20obliterate%20completes%2C%20it,as%20being%20under%20Perforce%20control).

To answer the previous popular answer.  You may not want cached/compiled/user settings in your depot as clients could create these for themselves.  A delete will cause all clients to need to recompile while an obliterate would likely accomplish the task at hand.  You may want to mark the files as writeable prior so that way they aren't left as read-only on clients depending on your `p4 typemap`